# How I can get newline represented by string "" from .txt file (not talking about \n) in python

Tags: python

If I'll create tab in notepad and then copy that to python code in string "" it works.

How can I get enter, newline as string? I don't want \n that will be represented as newline in print statement I want newline that will be understood by python if I'll get it from the .txt file. Example

`my_file = open("output.txt", "r")
print(my_file.read())
my_file.close()`

If you will copy question you will see what I mean. Output text is like this:

``` 1
``
2 ```

`` is enter

When I copy each character into new variable output I get is like this when I write text back

`1
2`

I want to store in some way newline in variable when I get it from text file.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Are you looking for a string literal, or something else?

Comment: When you open notepad and press enter you get new line. I want to copy that new line into string "" right now if I'll get text from notepad it's returned as single line.

Comment: See my post:  use a triple quoted string, so put `"""   """` around it.

Comment: You need to add more context as it is not clear at all what you are asking

Comment: Not really sure what you're on about, but maybe you're after `"\r\n"` which is the Windows line delimiter? (It should all be taken care of for you, though).

Comment: I can add `\r\n` or `\n` but how I can get it from text file and store as string or variable? I pretty much can store everything from .txt file except of newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the idea of using the '\n' representation for newline character is because it is a control character.

There are about 30 control characters in ASCII table and they are used to instruct devices ('\n' for new line, '\t' for tabulator, '\a' for beep, etc.), rather than represent some printable information. That means that they are in the file, they even have their own number in ASCII table like letters and numbers, but you can't see them in the file.

So if you need to put them somewhere, you usually use the '\n' representation. Don't worry, Python knows that and will place newline into the string instead of '\n', so I would recommend you to use '\n'. There is another way to put a newline into a Python string. You can append a character from ASCII table to string by its number.

Example:

```
mystring = ""
mystring += "First line"
mystring += chr(10)     //number of newline in ASCII is 10
mystring += "Second line"
```

Comment: That's closest to what I need! I still want to convert ASCII 10 into string is this possible or I need to create workaround for that?

Comment: If you need to create a string that contains one specific ASCII character or append the character to a string, you can use `chr(x)` function.

Comment: I not only need to create but to store it as well that's probably the biggest problem

Comment: You can write the character into a file and then read it, but you won't see it in your text editor. That's the idea of nonprintable control characters. You can, however, see them in some binary text editor.

Comment: Well seems like I'll have to work on that, this is closest to answer what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It really is no different to any other programming language.  `\n` is understood as a newline if you get it from a file opened in text mode.

It is not tied to the print statement, so

```
enter = '\n'
```

is valid. The characters `\n` are translated to the newline for your platform by python.

If you open in binary mode then you might need something else, on Windows typically `\r\n`.

However to answer your question, you can use a triple quoted string:

```
>>> x = """
... """
```

But, that is just a newline!

```
>>> x
'\n'
```